# List of Sites or Rooms with Coordinates in microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing a geolocation aware universal app using the Microsoft graph. We want to read a list of rooms or sites with it's address and the coordinates.

I can't find a suitable object neither in v1.0 nor beta version of Microsoft graph. There is the **beta/me/findRooms** API returning a list of rooms with its mail address but no other information.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there already an API for nodes representing Sites or Rooms where we have physical addresses or coordinates on?
2. If not, which object should be best used to be schema extended with coordinates?
3. Is it possible to introduce our own node, e.g. a Site plus a relationship to **/user** named something like PRESENT_AT?

So finally, we want to store something like User-[PRESENT_AT]->Site/Room{coordinates}

Comment: Anyone any advise ?